# Are there any jurisdictions in the world where dueling is still legal?

Tags: criminal-law, legal-history, dueling

Is there any place in the world where it is still legally possible to kill someone in a duel and not be charged? If not, when and where was the last place to outlaw the practice?

Comment: Incidentally, dueling was illegal in a lot of places *long* before it went out of fashion.

Comment: I suppose you mean duelling outside of organised competition (e.g. fencing)? Also, for the last duel [this answer from History SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/a/9368/15283) may be informative.

Comment: You could add this: In which countries is killing or injuring a person in a fair duel treated substantially different from murder or assault or battery?

Comment: Also, this depends on the definition of "dueling". Arguably, boxing could be considered a form of duel, at least in the sense that injuring the opponent (inflicting a concussion) is the goal. I imagine some cultures may allow or tolerate practices that fall somehwere in the spectrum between a "duel" as understood in Europe or the USA, and things like boxing.

Comment: It was outlawed, on a state by state basis, in most U.S. states where it had been legal in the 19th century, often with a provision in a state constitution to that effect. So the last jurisdiction to have outlawed it couldn't have been any later than the late 19th century and was probably more recent. Also, I don't think that all forms of combat by agreement constitute duels. A duel assumes that the purpose of combat by agreement is to resolve a dispute or failure to apologize for an affront to someone's honor. Combat by agreement to see who is a better fighter is not a duel.

Comment: @sleske more specifically, until one party gave up.  That may have required a knock *out* blow, but also knock *down*.  Men encouraged this to boys with disagreements: fight honorably, and then shake hands when one is defeated.

Answer (score 10):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duel#Legislation), duelling was legal in Uruguay from 1921 to 1971. It cites [this article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/744132) and I have found in the source that the law was passed in 1920, although I haven't found that it ended in 1971. However, several politically motivated duels [were fought in Uruguay in 1971](http://www.lr21.com.uy/comunidad/481143-los-ultimos-duelos), and [one newspaper claimed at least one of them to be legal](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1955&dat=19711018&id=PQgrAAAAIBAJ&sjid=cpgFAAAAIBAJ&pg=6515,4940475&hl=en).

Answer (score 2):

There are many parts of the world that are still tribal and governed by tribal laws. (e.g., Many parts of Central America, South America, Africa, Afghanistan, outside of Kabul, etc.)

I would imagine dueling is probably legal in one or more of those places.